# SQL Server 2008 Varbinary(Max) column - 28Mb of images creating 3.2Gb database

Tags: sql-server, image

This is the first time I've tried to store images in my DB instead of the file server and I'm regretting it so far. I can't use filestream because my host doesn't support it so I'm using a varbinary(max) column. I'm keeping track of the image sizes I insert and there's about 28Mb so far but the database is at 3.2Gb which is just crazy. Am I better to varbinary(XXXX) to reduce this - is SQL Server reserving space for the MAX?

Using MS SQL Server 2008 btw

Here is the top Table sizes:

```
TableName   RowCounts   TotalSpaceKB    UsedSpaceKB UnusedSpaceKB
Municipality    1028316 64264   64232   32
Image   665 33616   33408   208
User    320 248 224 24
SettingUser 5910    264 160 104
Region  1418    136 136 0
ImageUser   665 56  56  0
ConversationItem    164 56  56  0
Setting 316 48  48  0
Culture 378 40  40  0
UserTrack   442 40  40  0
Numbers 1000    32  32  0
Country 240 32  32  0
Conversation    52  32  32  0
CountryIp   0   88  32  56
ReportUser  0   16  16  0
ConversationItemImage   0   16  16  0
```

Here's the result for exec sp_spaceused:

```
database_size   unallocated space
3268.88 MB  0.84 MB

reserved    data    index_size  unused
359592 KB   291744 KB   66600 KB    1248 KB
```

I should probably also mention that there is a Geography Column on the Municiplity Table too in case this has any impact due to spatial indexes... I've used this plenty of times in the past and had no issues but I've never had 1M+ records either usually less than 20k

Comment: I personally would not use SQL for file storage. Just store the metadata in the db and use the file system for storing the actual file. Its just not worth using SQL unless you have small say kilobyte files.

Comment: The average image size for 600+ images is 43Kb I was of the understanding the Varbinary was ok for anything under 1mb but I'm inclined to agree with you - this was a trial and so far I am not that thrilled with it

Comment: It makes me think of the Single Responsibilty Principal poster with the Swiss Army knife poster 'Just Because You Can Doesn't Mean You Should'. Good Luck.

Comment: I have a good reason for attempting to use the db - the images are of a sensitive nature, using the db reduces the chances of someone from my hosting account coming across them... I well aware of the two schools of thought on this matter - The question wasn't about whether or not I should do this...

Comment: @Rob out of curiosity, how much of that space is used by your log file?

Comment: @TheVedge thank you for posing that question - I just got word from the hosting provider that the log file was 2.9Gb and they've shrunk it down to 350MB - I shrank the database locally before restoring to the remote host - the backup was 400MB I'm not sure where the inflation happened maybe I didn't shrink it correctly.

Comment: @TheVedge if you'd like to word you comment as an answer I will mark it as correct :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that all that space is being used by the actual data, and not the log file.

Shrinking the log file will only remove unused space. In order to clear entries before shrinking it, you would need to backup or truncate the log before hand (Warning: If you care at all about your log chain, this could break it)